# Python PIL Choose Fonts According to Language

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow to add texts to different images. Most of the time `Roboto.ttf` fonts are well enough. But sometimes there're unicode chars such as Japanese Kanji and Korean characters that `Roboto` cannot display.

For aesthetic reasons I want to keep using `Roboto` if possible. But if there's a unicode type object such as "都道312号線", I'd like to apply another font like `unicode.ttf`. Right now I'm getting weird symbols using `Roboto`, resulting in "??312??".

I'm using ImageDraw.Draw(img).text(position, inputtext, font=font), where inputtext is of unicode type. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that ImageDraw's default draw text module cannot switch fonts inside a single text string, so first thing would be to examine all of your drawing texts and split them up in runs of 'same script'. Then you'd have to assign a font to each script, and finally draw the runs. A casual Google search did not turn up a good source for `ImageFont`, so I cannot recommend if inspecting the font object in advance would be useful.

Comment: @Jongware thanks for your advice. I've solved the issue by detecting CJK chars first and then choose fonts accordingly. There're many answers on how to detect CJK chars on the Internet. Thanks a lot.